# Align label in middle of textarea in separate divs

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, class, razor

I have following code and I want to make my label to be alligned in middle near textarea:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Message", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.TextArea("Message", new { @class = "form-control", rows = 10, style="vertical-align:middle;"})
    </div>
</div>
```

It still appears at top of textarea...

P.S In single div it works fine, but I have to remove form-control and col classes... Here's code which makes label aligned in middle near textarea:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.Label("Message", new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.TextArea("Message", new { rows = 10, style="vertical-align:middle;"})
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas how to make that alignment without changing divs and classes of the first code?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's possible without an intervention using margins. The following should give you what you are looking for :

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Message", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label", @style="margin-top: 80px" })
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.TextArea("Message", new { @class = "form-control", rows = 10, style="vertical-align:middle;"})
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for idea, but I believe it is another way to make it in middle without knowing row count ant setting up pixels, because textarea might be different size because of class or rows count, so I am still looking for ideas and trying to think of something else too. :)

Comment: Yes, I figured. I will be interested in knowing the correct answer too!